# 123.SOGOU.COM - trojan horse in ukui-screensaver

Tags: firefox, screensaver, trojan

Firefox's default page is 123.sogou.com and I can't remove it. I've tried to reset and re-install it, but it keeps going back to sogou.

Comment: If that issue was introduced by the original package in the repos it should be bug-reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ukui-screensaver) to give the people maintaining that package a heads up.

Comment: As far as I can tell, sougou.com is a legitimate search engine and the default on Ubuntu Kylin, rather than any kind of malware or trojan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sogou. If I am wrong, then please file a report with evidence with the Ubuntu Kylin developers against `ubuntukylin-default-settings` (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntukylin-default-settings/+filebug).

Comment: See also [How can PPAs be removed?](/q/307/175814) and [Remove all packages installed from a PPA?](/q/363653/175814)

Answer (score 7):

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10. Screensaver was not going on, then I went to Software Center and installed the first screensaver I got in search result. It led to set Firefox's default page as 123.sogou.com. I didn't imagine it was due to the screensaver util I read the post http://www.gabrielemerli.com/?p=3381. I tried to remove Firefox and all config files and cache, still dammed sogou was there. After reading the post from Gabriele, I remove the screensaver ukui-screensaver and also ubuntukylin-default-settings. Here is what I did to restore Firefox defaults.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ukui-screensaver 
$ sudo apt-get remove ubuntukylin-default-settings 
$ sudo apt-get remove firefox 
$ rm -rf ~/.config/mozilla
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntukylin.list
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntukylin.list.save
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get autoclean 
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the member of Ubuntu Kylin, and I'm sorry for bring your the trouble, I will fix this in next release. And now you can:

```
$ sudo rm  /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/all-ubuntukylin.js
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/firefox/ubuntukylin.cfg
```

Then edit homepage in about:preferences, and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and removing everything  with "kylin" in it resolved the issue. I have no idea how it found its way in my system:

Just list them:

```
apt list --installed | grep -i kylin
```

Then install everything you see in that list. This is probably a cleaner way to get rid of it rather than deleting files individually.