# How to remove sogou as default startpage?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox I currently have as startpage 123.sogou.com, but I am not able to remove the website as my startpage. Every time I am changing the default page in Firefox back to Google, it automatically turns back to sogou after a restart. Any idea how to remove this?

I also tried the steps from [123.SOGOU.COM - trojan horse in ukui-screensaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970219/123-sogou-com-trojan-horse-in-ukui-screensaver), but it has not changed anything.

Comment: do you by any chances have the package `ukui-screensaver` installed? You can check that with `apt policy ukui-screensaver`.

Comment: No, I have not. I also tried the steps from https://askubuntu.com/questions/970219/123-sogou-com-trojan-horse-in-ukui-screensaver?rq=1, but it has not changed anything.

Comment: O.k. try to recall what you installed lately, and check those packages maybe as well try to remember which pages you surfed. It is weird to see the second question about this in a week.

Comment: Are you running ubuntu ? What did you install when this started ? Any ppa ?

Comment: Or did you per accident install Ubuntu Kylin? there it is preinstalled by default I think.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, see comment " I also tried the steps from askubuntu.com/questions/970219/…, but it has not changed anything" will edit the question.

Comment: @Panther I wish the OP would actually remember what he installed. from my testing in a sandboxed VM I found out that the screen-saver in the other QA is indeed one of the culprits and he normally belongs to Ubuntu-Kylin. and from what i have read on the net it seems including this search site into Firefox was one of the requirements to distribute Ubuntu on the chinese market (but that are rumors  mostly, could not find any official about it). and the worst is, ukui-screensaver appears as top 2. entry if you search for screen-saver in the software center.

Comment: mate-screensaver package is the same and this is the top most search result in software-center, just it doesnt lock you 123.sugou.com it in fact lock you on start.ubuntu-mate.com without a chance to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed exactly the same problem today. 
Solutions from this thread, and from the linked one didn't help me.
My last installed apps was:

- arandr
- gnome-tweak-tool
- ubuntu-desktop

I am not sure if any of them could trigger this issue.

Working solution for me was:

- Open Firefox
- type about:support in address bar and enter the page
- Click on "Refresh firefox" (or something similar)

After that operation, 123.sogou.com won't opens anymore

Answer (score 0):

I found a file in /usr/lib/firefox which sets the homepage. To find it, I did a simple "grep -Hnri sogou *" hoping that the address would be part of a skript. In my case, it was a file named "ubuntukylin.cfg". Instead of simply deleting this single file, I deleted all packages with "kylin" in their names (I use XFCE4 so this shouldn't matter). This removed the file. Firefox calls now the correct homepage.